# How can I modified page (31) Item List, after I Post Item Journal in Ms. NAVISION

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2016

I wanna make alert while item in inventory <= safety stock quantity, so I create new field "Out Of Stock" in table Item (27), and I put this code in Page Item List (31) in OnAfterGetRecord() trigger.

IF (Inventory <= "Safety Stock Quantity") THEN
  VALIDATE("Out Of Stock",TRUE)
ELSE
  CLEAR("Out Of Stock");

It's working but if I filter 'Out Of Stock" in List the filter is weird. I must modify this page after post journal,but in OnAfterGetRecord() trigger cannot modify.

Answer (score 0):

You must update (not the page but Item table) when any inventory action is performed in the system. Anything that changes table 32 (Item Ledger Entry).

I believe there is a way to do it w/o development. You can run Reorder function pereodically and if it is creating order proposals for certain item then inventory is low. Depends on setups.